# Bosun metrics rate - what is "auto" or default value?

Tags: bosun

I am very curious what is default value of metrics' rating. It seems it is not one of the three - gauge, counter, rate. And documentation doesn't contain any "auto" type. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bosun stores metadata about metrics. When using scollector, most metrics have a piece of metadata that says if is a counter or a gauge. If that metadata is available, "auto" will select the appropriate one based on metadata. If there is no metadata, auto should error.